# Stackoverflow error while checking InvokeRequired

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stack-overflow, invokerequired

I'm getting a stackverflow error while executing InvokeRequired.

System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

[image]

How to fix it?
There is no info i View Details.

FIXED VERSION:

```
    public DialogResult ShowMessage(string msg, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Func<DialogResult> m = () => MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, buttons);
            return (DialogResult)Invoke(m);
        }
        else
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(msg, caption, buttons);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, it's considered best practice to post the code here, instead of an image. It's easier to create a correct code example that way, based on the code you already have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because when `InvokeRequired` is true, you call the exact same method again and again. You need to use [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) in order to get the method scheduled to run on the UI thread. In this case, `InvokeRequired` will be false, and your code will run into the `if` branch where you actually show the dialog.

Change your code to something along the lines of:

```
if(InvokeRequired) 
{
    Func<DialogResult> showMsg = () => ShowMessage(msg, caption, buttons);
    return (DialogResult)Invoke(showMsg);
}
```

Comment: You need to change the delegate type to `Func<DialogResult>` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a stackoverflow because the ShowMessage method is stuck in an infinitive loop, because it calls itself over and over when "InvokeRequired"